# Is (value)mask in XCreateGC() really necessary?

Tags: c, x11

The third argument of [XCreateGC()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/GC/XCreateGC.html) is a valuemask, but is it really necessary?

```
GC XCreateGC (display, d, valuemask, values)

Display *display;
Drawable d;
unsigned long valuemask; // Specifies which components in the GC are to be set
                         // using the information in the specified values structure.
                         // This argument is the bitwise inclusive OR of zero or
                         // more of the valid GC component mask bits.
XGCValues *values;       //`Specifies any values as specified by the valuemask.
```

We can set every element in [XGCValues structure](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/GC/manipulating.html#XGCValues), so why we have to use mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way you control which values are actually sent to server over the wire. `CreateGC` request is of variable length and can be from 16 to 108 bytes length depending on what values you actually have in your `valuemask`. This might be not a big deal these days, but X11 protocol was designed 30 years ago in 1984 and is actually quite efficient both in terms of throughput and latency when used correctly